# Check 'mousewheel' event direction with scroll locked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I currently have a slick slider on top of my page that should change slides on scroll, and after a certain point it should go back to normal scroll behaviour.

What I want to do is to initially lock the scroll (yeah, I know that changing scroll behaviour is a terrible thing for UX, but this was a mandatory request that came directly from the client), check the amount of times the scroll event was fired, check if it was up or down, and then switch slides accordingly.

My code currently looks like this:

```
$('body').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
  var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
      firstWaypoint = viewportHeight / 2,
      secondWaypoint = viewportHeight,
      thirdWaypoint = 3/2 * viewportHeight,
      unlockPoint = viewportHeight * 2,
      $slider = $('.home-hero__inner__text');

  if (/* Y scroll position < thirdWaypoint lock scroll */) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (/* If Y scroll position < secondWaypoint show first slide */) {
    $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);
  } else if (/* If Y scroll position > secondWaypoint show second slide */) {
    $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 1);
  } else if (/* If Y scroll position > thirdWaypoint show third slide */) {
    $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 2);
  } else {
    // Unlock scroll
  }
});
```

The thing is that as I currently lock scroll capabilities using *preventDefault()*, I can no longer check my page *scrollTop()* position since it is always at the top, *returning a 0 value*.

Is there a way to check how many pixels should've been scrolled on normal behaviour, and whether it was up or down? 'cause **I need to keep a track of the assumed scroll position** to trigger each step of the *if statement*.

Comment: DOMMouseScroll is a Mozilla thing and uses 'details' to give feedback as to the direction of the mousewheel movement. mousewheel uses 'delta' to give the same feedback. The exception is that 'details' and 'delta' are the reverse of each other. (i.e., the up on one is the down of the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check if the `wheelDelta` is positive or negative

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e) {
    var moved = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail * -1 || 0;

    if (moved > 0) {
        // scrolled up
    } else if (moved < 0) {
        // scrolled down
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lwp3c5br/)

Comment: Thanks, even though it didn't end up of being useful for my case, your answer worked like a charm and was pretty self-explanatory!